# grok regex pattern matching

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, regular-language

I want to find the grok pattern for this:

```
INFO: 200000 packets. Current packet is class com.navtech.kernel.flat.FlatCombo [Loader] [tstamp: 1866 time: 1851.4 (30:51) split: 03.2] [Memory: 3.320G total: 22.20G free: 18.88G]
```

I tried

```
\A(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level})%{GREEDYDATA:message}\s(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+(\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+)+(\[%{DATA:ts}\]\s+)+(\[%{DATA:mem}\])
```

but now what I'm missing is to extract the "Memory:" and "total:" so how will I write regular expression for that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have all 3: `Memory: 3.320G total: 22.20G free: 18.88G`, `3.320G` and `22.20G`? Right now, you have 1 `mem`: `"mem": [
    "Memory: 3.320G total: 22.20G free: 18.88G"
  ]`

Comment: Or do you want to remove `mem` and only get `"memory": [ "3.320G" ]` and `"total": [ "22.20G" ]`?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, all 3 would be fine but I couldn't figure out to use the 3.320 without G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+(\[%{DATA:ts}\]\s+)+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?\])
```

Where `%{DATA:mem}` is replaced with `\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?`:

- `\s*\S+\s+` - 0+ whitespaces, 1+ chars other than whitespace and 1+ whitespaces (we are skipping `Memory:`)
- `%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*` - memory value consisting of a number + zero or more non-whitespace symbols after the number
- `\s+\S+\s+` - 1+ whitespaces, 1+ chars other than whitespace and 1+ whitespaces (we are skipping `total:`)
- `%{BASE10NUM:total}` - `total` value that is a number
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars up to the first `]`

See the test screen:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I tried the same but I tweaked it a little 
`^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+(\[%{DATA:ts}\]\s+)+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{NOTSPACE:used_memory}\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total_memory}.*?\])` 

but when I'm changing the NOTSPACE in used_memory with BASE10NUM  I'm getting no match, what do you think of the problem

Comment: I am updating the answer. Use `^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+(\[%{DATA:ts}\]\s+)+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?\])`

Comment: And if you also need to keep `mem`, use `^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+(\[%{DATA:ts}\]\s+)+(\[\s*(?<mem>\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?)\s*\])`

Comment: Do not copy text from the comments as SO inserts garbled chars there for better appearance. Copy from the answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad, Thanks

Comment: one more thing Sir, I am having trouble under standing \s+\S+\s+ and \s*\S+\s+ usage also if I wanted to remove ts and replace with tstamp like the one done by you on memory field

Comment: I explained all these patterns. `\s` stands for whitespace and `\S` stands for any char but whitespace. `*` means 0 or more occurrences. `+` means 1 or more occurrences. Replace `\[%{DATA:ts}\]` with something like `\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10N‌​UM:tstamp}.*?\]`

Comment: getting compile error with this
`^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10N‌​UM:tstamp}.*?\]\s+)+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?\])`

Comment: Again, garbled chars? I do not get any issues, copy from [here](https://regex101.com/r/yMq9J1/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it right.
why does this garbled chars issue arise ?

Comment: Ask SO developers. I only think those zero width joiners they insert help comments look nicer.